# expose nodejs library in nodejs public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there any way to reference a Nodejs library included in **node_modules** folder from a ejs view?

I'm using **expressjs** and my client libraries are served form **/public** folder as depicted below, so I'm not being able to reach the **node_modules** folder from a ejs view

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), it seems you can serve modules directly from node_modules. See the [documentation on requirejs and node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

Example:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['some_module'], function(some_module) {
    // Here, some_module will be loaded from your node_modules
});
```

**Old answer:**

You can use [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) in express to expose properties or functions to your views.

See the example from the docs (linked above):

```
app.locals.title = 'My App';
app.locals.strftime = require('strftime');
```

Comment: yes, I know but I'd rather want to access to the file. As an include from the view like <script src="my-nodejs-module.js">, actually I'm using requirejs on the client side so I want to reference that library from my main.js file

Comment: Oh, you want to serve it to the client? You should clarify your question, I think -- it reads as if you want to use it in the ejs template.